# Jquery linking to another tab

Tags: jquery, tabs

I have some tabs which are working fine and are adding an 'active' class when clicked. I want to have text links within the tabs content linking to each other. I have this working but I just can't find a way to get its tab to be active:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sarah3585/01vas55s/

So here I want to apply the active class to tab2 when the link to it is clicked within tab1.

HTML:

```
<div class="tabs">
        <div class="selection">
        <ul class="tab-links">
            <li class="active"><a class="tab-link button" href="#tab1">Button1</a></li>
            <li><a class="tab-link button" href="#tab2">Button 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

  <div class="internal-container tab-content">

    <div id="tab1" class="tab active"> 
        Tab 1 content
        <a href="#tab2" class="tab-link">Link to tab2</a>
    </div>

    <div id="tab2" class="tab"> 
        Tab 2 content
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('a.tab-link').on('click', function(e)  {
    var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');

    // Show/Hide Tabs
    $('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).show().siblings().hide();

    // Change/remove current tab to active
    $(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

    e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
$(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
```

With

```
$('a[href='+currentAttrValue+']').parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
```